# Insert table into word in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create instance of Document class

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
```

How i can insert table and text into special position in Document ?
For example after or before one bookmark

Comment: Do it in Word manually with the macro recorder running, looking at the generated VBA will show you what methods to call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add text in word doc, you can use

```
Word.Range rng = this.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0);
 rng.Text = "New Text";
```

for table:

```
 Word.Range tableLocation = this.Range(ref start, ref end);
 this.Tables.Add(tableLocation, 10, 11);
```

check this link for [text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b9478cs.aspx) and [table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1702h4a.aspx).

```
Set rangeStart = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("YourFirstBookmark").Range
Set rangeEnd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("YourEndBookmark").Range

var range= Range(rangeStart.Start, rangeEnd.End)
```

Comment: I want get Range between 2 Bookmarks no Range(0, 0)